# Planet Orbit Counter clockwise insead of Clockwise

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I made a game where planets orbit clockwise (More of a simulation). I'm wondering how I would make it go counter clockwise.

Host = the object the planet is orbiting

entity = planet

```
double angle;
            if (host.Y == entity.Y && host.X == entity.X) //small offset
                angle = Math.Atan2(host.Y - entity.Y + (Random.NextDouble()*2 - 1),
                    host.X - entity.X + (Random.NextDouble()*2 - 1));
            else
                angle = Math.Atan2(host.Y - entity.Y, host.X - entity.X);
            float angularSpd = host.GetSpeed(s.Speed)/s.Radius;
            angle += angularSpd*(time.thisTickTimes/1000f);

            double x = entity.X + Math.Cos(angle)*radius;
            double y = entity.Y + Math.Sin(angle)*radius;
            Vector2 vect = new Vector2((float) x, (float) y) - new Vector2(host.X, host.Y);
            vect.Normalize();
            vect *= host.GetSpeed(s.Speed)*(time.thisTickTimes/1000f);

            host.MoveTo(host.X + vect.X, host.Y + vect.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `angle += angularSpd...` to `angle -= angularSpd...`

Comment: Pfft... I'm absolutely dumb. Thanks for your answer! It works.